# Which isolation level do I need?

Tags: mysql, database-design, isolation-level

I've read a lot of articles about Isolation levels, but I'm confused which one to choose for my MySQL 5.6 database.

This is my situation:

> Let's say I have two group of users:
>
> 1. Group A (executes selects)
> 2. Group B (executes inserts and updates)

Every individual in group A is executing huge select query that takes 5 minutes and in the meanwhile a couple members from group B are inserting and updating records.

**Which database isolation do I need to achieve:**

1. The select queries that are executed by people from Group A should
   NOT cause a **lock** to eachother. So simultaneously reads should be
   allowed, they must be able to access the same data at the same time.
2. The select queries that are executed by people from Group A should
   NOT cause a **lock** to people from Group B who are inserting and
   updating. So simultaneously writes and reads should be allowed and
   people from Group B shouldn't be waiting 5 minutes until the individual select
   queries from Group A are finished.
3. The inserted and updated records should be included in the select
   query results from Group A.

Answer (score 0):

A slow `SELECT` that can be sped up by adding a composite index or reformulating the query will mostly avoid getting blocked.

Ditto for inefficient `INSERTs` and other queries.

What is your setting for `tx_isolation`?  Changing that to `READ UNCOMMITTED` for the long `SELECT` may help.

Is this a Data Warehouse application and the `SELECT` is a 'report'?  If so, consider building and maintaining a Summary table.  This makes reports much faster.

Consider Master-Slave setup, with the long `SELECTs` going to the Slave.

You *are* using InnoDB, *not* MyISAM, correct?

If you want more specific advice, please provide (at least) `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT`.